# <form> and Jquery ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I got the following HTML form

```js
 function FormSubmit (){
        $.ajax({
            url:'dotar.php',
            type:'post',
            data:$('form').serialize(),
            success:function(){
                setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
```

```html
<form method="post">
     <input type="text" required></input>
     <submit id="submit"><button onclick="FormSubmit()">Go</button></submit>
    </form>
```

Im new to ajax so i might have a newbie mistake, but why the "success" alert message only pop up when I didnt fill the name input when it should be the opossite?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there is no `<submit>` element, and inputs are self-closing.

Secondly, a button inside a form will submit the form and redirect the page, so the alert is never shown.
The reason it works when you don't type anything in the input, is because the input is `required` and if it's empty, the form won't be submitted, and the alert pops up.

Change your code

```
<form method="post" id="myForm">
   <input type="text" required="required">
   <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

and then do

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent submit

    $.ajax({
        url     : 'dotar.php',
        type    : 'post',
        data    : $(this).serialize(),
        success : function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                alert("Hello"); 
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up a few things in your HTML:

1. There is no "*submit*" element.
2. An "*input*" element is a self closing tag, no need to explicitly close it.
3. Attach your "*FormSubmit*" function to the "*onsubmit*" event to have it executed on form submission (or better- look at the bottom of my answer for the more appropriate way using jQuery).

Try this example:

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" method="post" onsubmit="FormSubmit()">
   <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required/>
   <button id="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
function FormSubmit (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
           url:'dotar.php',
           type:'post',
           data:$('#form').serialize(),
           success:function(data){
               setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000);
           }
       });
}
```

Another more modern and reliable way to attach your javascript to a form's submit event in a clean and neat way:

```
$('#form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
});
```

**SIDE NOTE**

If you want to support old IE browsers, the inline *onsubmit* in the form tag might not work - in that case you should (as I mentioned above) use:

`$('#myForm').on('submit',function(){/*my code*/});`

Hope it helps a bit